# Do I need SQLite in order to store some data on MySQL database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

If I need to store some data on MySQL database, should I first store it on SQLite then sync SQLite on Android to MySQL database?

Is it possible to store the data to MySQL database without having SQLite ? If yes, what's the better option  ? (with SQLite or without it)

**update** 
I need MySQL becase I want *person1* to be able to see *person2's* data, which is not possible if *person2's* data was stored on SQLite, because it will be sitting in *person2's* Android device.. am I right?

Comment: Why do you want to store data in `MySQL` when you have a very lightweight DB called `SQLite`?

Comment: To my knowledge you can't have MySQL database on android phone. I also don't see any benefit in this.

Comment: @thelostmind I updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: @Lamorak I updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. So you mean a MySQL database on server?

Comment: @Lamorak Yes.  (So in my case I really need a MySQL database, and can't have only SQLite ?)

Comment: well you can have any database you want on the server. if you need to cache you data in the phones for offline use you need the sqlite but you can do without it

Comment: Look at my answer for full comment

Answer (score 2):

The question is where do you want to put your database ? If in-app then there is no other choice but SQLite.

If it's off-app then the possibilities are limitless. You can run your own server and MySql database for sure. If you use cloud solutions like those offered by Amazon AWS for example, you won't even need to setup a server because they have SDK that allows the app to communicate directly with the database.

Syncing strategy depends on your app. Maybe it is not needed and your app can send queries to your db on demand basis. My rule of thumb is I resist setting database in the client or app. Why ? Because once it's there, modifying it won't be easy. Plus it's at the mercy of settings->clear data or uninstall.

If you want to do what your edit says then you need to do it off-app. You need a central database that collects data from all installs and allows queries from them. I need to emphasize that if it's off-app it doesn't need to be MySql. MySql is just a kind of relational database system. You can use schemaless systems (or NoSql), file storage (if the data are files), etc which all depend on many considerations.

Answer (score 1):

Android only supports SQLite database which will be sitting in your app on the Android device.

If you want to use a MySQL database you will need to create an API that will be sitting on a server somewhere on the internet. This API will create an interface from your application to the MySQL database. You will then need to make network calls to your API from your Android App.

There are loads of options using an API model so really you will need to do some Googling and work out what works best for you.

**Edit**

To answer your edited question, you will definitely need to have a design pattern using an API. If you are creating a service that needs to be accessed from multiple devices then it is usually the way to go. The benefit of using an API is that they can be used cross-platform. So not only will you be able to use it on an Android device, you may be able to use it via the Web, IOS app etc...

A simple and typical architecture to get you going is that you have an Android App which will send network calls to an API over the web via HTTP. The API will be sitting on a server that may have a MySQL database stored on there. The API will authenticate your user and carry out the method required which will probably do some database query. Once the API has the results, it will send it back to the Android App which will be parsed and displayed to the user.

It's a massive topic so really you need to do a bit of research on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support MySQL to save application data, as you can see mentioned on the [developer.android website.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Although, you are not compel to use the SQLite Database to be able to comunicate with other RDBMS. You can see this [example,](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database) that shows you how to retrieve a data records from a remote MySQL database using JSON, PHP and HTTP requests.

I think that you can also have a look at [ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html). They are usually used with SQLite but I think that it may work with other RDBMS.

Comment: If by pearson1 and 2 you refer to 2 different mobile terminals, and they have to be able to retrieve registers from a comun database, they will have to be both conected to a comun database (one that you store on a server, not on one of the mobile phones). It does not matter what type of RDBMS you have on the server (MySQL, SQLite, Oracle, Access...), use the one you feel more comfortable, and when retrieving data just put it into a java Collections Object (e.g.: HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>, where key is the Primary Key from your database and the restant atributes goes to the ArrayList.